# Python Tkinter: Reading Serial Values

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I would like to read serial values into my Tkinter GUI. Either into a text window or eventually to a text label widget which updates every second or so. The issue I am having is with the queue class. The error I am getting is: 
AttributeError: 'Applcation' object has no attribute 'queue'

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from time import sleep
import picamera
import os
import serial
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import _thread
import threading
import random
import queue

# Setup GPIO pin(s) 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, False)


#==============================================================
# Declaration of Constants
# none used

#==============================================================

class SerialThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def read_sensor_values(self):
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
        while True:
            if ser.inWaiting:
                text = ser.readline(s.inWaiting)
                self.queue.put(text)
                self.pressures_txt.insert(0.0,values)






class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI Application for taking photos. """

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.setup_camera()

    def create_widgets(self):

    Checkbutton( self, text = "Read Pressure Values", variable = self.mode2, command = self.process_serial, bg = 'white').grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    # create text field to display pressure values from arduino
        self.pressures_txt = Text(self, height = 3, wrap = WORD)
        self.pressures_txt.grid(row=9, column = 0, columnspan =3)

    def process_serial(self):
        #self.text.delete(1.0, END)
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                self.text.insert(END, self.queue.get())
                self.pressures_txt.insert(0.0, self.queue.get())
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
        self.after('1000', self.process_serial)
     #................. end of method: read_sensor_values ................


#=================================================================
# main
#=================================================================

root = Tk()                             # Create the GUI root object
root.title("Control V1.0")
app = Application(root)                 # Create the root application window
root.mainloop()
```

The code I have posted is an abbreviated version of the entire program. I have removed sections that are supposedly irrelevant. I am running in python3. I suspect I may have an error in indentation but I am not certain.

I am using the code from the following link for my serial reading class:

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/496499/using-a-checkbutton-to-import-serial-data-into-python-tkinter

Comment: Well, your application object has no queue, just like the error says. Is the application object supposed to have a queue?

Comment: I would like to have the values from the serial thread inserted into the text window in my application object. From browsing around I saw that generally the way to do this was through a queue, but admittedly I don't entirely understand the queue process or how to access the queue inside of the application object from a different object. The values should be continuously streaming so I supposed that I do not need the .inWaiting either. Any advice on how to read these serial values in my application object would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `self.queue` in `read_sensor_values` belongs to a `SerialThread` object.  When you say `self.queue` in the `process_serial` method of your `Application` object, it refers to a non-existent `queue` attribute of the `Application` object.  Perhaps you ought to make the `SerialThread` object an attribute of your `Application` object.  Then `process_serial` could refer to `self.serial.queue` or whatever you name it.